# Persist an object even after session gets expire

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, object, system-design

I'm currently working on a POC in which I need to persist a unique object for each request. My application post a form on some other site and wait for the response from that site on my response handler. So I want to get that unique object on my response handler too.

I have tried of Session but what if session gets expired.

Comment: I think if you add more details about why you need this, you might get better advise here, but if you want to store something that does not expire, then DB is probably your best bet... thought you could save it in any other persistent storage.

Comment: Actually, to get from the DB I need an identifier but as I said the response from other application comes to my response handler and I don't have any identifier at that point of time

Answer (score 0):

Store the object in DB and store the DB identifier in the cookie. Then you will have the DB identifier on every request. Also send this identifier to the other site and when you get it back you know what to process.

Instead of cookie you can also store the data in the browser storage if cookie is disabled.

Comment: What if the user has disabled the cookies?

Comment: User could have cookie or javascript disabled. For that you can detect and block the user from using the functionality without enabling cookie or javascript. Otherwise you will have to send and get a token back to-from the site. Otherwise do not have many options.